# What sort of chat events could we schedule?

Tags: discussion, chat

There are usually a few individuals idling in [The Pod Bay](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9682/the-pod-bay), and it has a good level activity. I'd hate to see that activity slump as we move further into beta (as it seems to be with most sites).

I think a good way to keep the activity levels high would be to schedule chat events. What sort of events do you think would be interesting?

Comment: The main locus of activity should be the Q&A imho. That's what stays forever...

Comment: @Deer of course, these aren't meant to detract from Q&A, but rather promote activity on the site. Not a lot of Q&A typically goes on in chat rooms, but if we could schedule some sort of "interview with an expert" in chat, that would be fantastic. [Blender.SE] has done this twice: [Jonathan Williamson](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/q/90/199) followed by [Campbell Barton](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/q/222/199). Other sites have much more casual events, for example EE.SE has a weekly [hangout](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/15/electrical-engineering?tab=schedule)

Comment: This would be great. We [physics.se] folks have one every other Tuesday, and we have fun (or crickets, it oscillates). It's a nice way to promote community bonding.

Answer (score 3):

[Spaceflight Now - Worldwide launch schedule](http://spaceflightnow.com/tracking/)

[image: Spaceflight Now - Worldwide launch schedule]

<sup>Example schedule feed from [spaceflightnow.com](http://spaceflightnow.com/tracking/)</sup>

Website sadly doesn't host a RSS feed of its own, so <s>I've created it using [page2rss.com](http://page2rss.com/fa3d49dcfc67b6181f825695c9a856a7):</s>

- **[Worldwide launch schedule RSS feed](http://page2rss.com/rss/fa3d49dcfc67b6181f825695c9a856a7)**

@DeerHunter has prepared it using [feed43.com](http://www.feed43.com/):

- **[Space launch schedule RSS feed](http://www.feed43.com/space-launch-schedule.xml)**

**Notes**: The RSS feed converted from the Spaceflight Now web page that @DeerHunter prepared has a better format, especially the RSS feed titles make a lot more sense and are more descriptive than how `page2rss.com` parsed it.

---

We have already successfully hosted a live launch event in our chat room, [The Pod Bay](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9682/the-pod-bay), for the [ULA](http://www.ulalaunch.com/) Delta IV rocket launching the [Wideband Global SATCOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wideband_Global_SATCOM) satellite into orbit:

[image: Images from live feed of the ULA Delta IV rocket launching the Wideband Global SATCOM satellite]

<sup>Images from live feed of the [ULA](http://www.ulalaunch.com/) Delta IV rocket launching the 6th [Wideband Global SATCOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wideband_Global_SATCOM) satellite.</sup>

Looking forward to more live feeds covering launches throughout the world.

Comment: Nicely done, this one is likely to be more than useful so i integrated it into the feeds of the room. Will also use it to schedule events a few days in advance so we can gather up a nice crowd

Answer (score 3):

There are non-launch events too -

- Juno's Earth fly-by in October 2013,
- Cassini's Titan fly-by also in October 2013

to name just a couple.

Perhaps we may have SEx.SE events scheduled against non-launch events. These may not be accompanied by a video/data feed though ...

Answer (score 1):

NASA's [Project Morpheus](http://morpheuslander.jsc.nasa.gov/) will often live stream their tests, and it can be pretty fun to watch:

[**Morpheus Live**](http://morpheuslander.jsc.nasa.gov/live/)

The issue with scheduling these is that they usually announce the tests *the day of the event*:

> Good morning world! It's a great [@NASA_Johnson](https://twitter.com/NASA_Johnson) day for a [#TetherTest](https://twitter.com/search?q=#TetherTest&src=hash). Join us for a great [#rocket](https://twitter.com/search?q=#rocket&src=hash) test fire. We'll go LIVE later on the web!
>
> — *[@MorpheusLander](https://twitter.com/MorpheusLander/status/365105648763015171)*

This makes it hard to schedule a chat event for it, but I think it would still be a good thing to help build our community.

Here's a truncated video of one of the streams:

[**Project Morpheus Tether Test 27**](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z68yXnEpzIE)

[image: Tether test]

Comment: Other space sites provide links to live broadcasts of rocket launches.

Answer (score 1):

Astrobites feed: http://astrobites.org/feed/

Answer (score 1):

Mars Daily feed: http://www.marsdaily.com/marsdaily.xml